# How do I put JSON strings in one JSONObject into arrays to sort them?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a .php file that outputs a list of products in a JSON format, but it creates one big JSON:

```
{"monumentid1":"1","name1":"Text","region1":"Text","monumentid2":"2","name2":"Text","region2":"Text","monumentid3":"3","name3":"Text","region3":"Text","monumentid4":"4","name4":"Text","region4":"Text","monumentid5":"111","name5":"Text","region5":"Text"}
```

...and I need to have each String sorted like this into arrays:

```
{"monument1":[{"monumentid1":"1"},{"name1":"Text"},{"region1":"Text"}]} etc.
```

is it possible to do in PHP? I need to work with that JSON later.

The PHP file I'm currently using:

```
class SeznamMagnetekApi extends BaseApi
{
public function ToProcess($parametry)
{
    $magnetkyInfo = Database::SqlGetFetchAll("select monumentid, name, region from monuments");

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($magnetkyInfo as $info)
    {
        $i++;
        $this->json['monumentid' . $i] = $info['monumentid'];
        $this->json['name' . $i] = $info['name'];
        $this->json['region' . $i] = $info['region'];
    }
}
```

}

And the BaseApi class:

```
abstract class BaseApi
{
protected $json = array();

abstract function ToProcess($parametry);

public function WriteJson()
{
    $this->json = json_encode($this->json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    echo $this->json;
}
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You did not explain what you are trying to do

Comment: I want to get a JSON output that is not one JSON object, but more JSON objects (one for each monument). Each monument has one monumentid,name and region value **edit** I meant more JSON arrays (one for each monument)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your desire output you can use this code:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($magnetkyInfo as $info)
{
    $i++;
    $arr[]['monumentid' . $i] = $info['monumentid'];
    $arr[]['name' . $i] = $info['name'];
    $arr[]['region' . $i] = $info['region'];
    $this->json['monumentid' . $i] = $arr;
}
```

BUT - i think it better to have 1 json object to it element as:

```
foreach ($magnetkyInfo as $info)
{
    $i++;
    $obj = ["monumentid" => $info["monumentid"], "name" => $info["name"], "region" => $info["region"]];
    $this->json['monumentid' . $i] = $obj;
}
```

Now, you have object with the id as array and each will be separate object inside (and not array)

Comment: Thank you, that looks much better and is significantly faster, but I have one problem, it outputs this: https://i.imgur.com/S6UTgKL.png (the code adds 0,1,2 to the JSON). Any idea what causes it?

Comment: @Etoile that because you SQL return bigger array (probably you using PDO or fetch associative somewhere) - edit the second way yo fix it

Comment: Thanks a lot, works like a charm! Thank you for making the world a better place :D :D